# Spring Boot : handleMethodArgumentNotValid overriding not working for date format mismatch

Tags: spring-boot, validation, exceptionhandler

I have an exception handler class that is working fine for validation failures.

The method **handleMethodArgumentNotValid** is not getting called for date type format mismatch **(dateOfBirth)** but works fine with **@Past** failure.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.demo.exception.handler;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import com.example.demo.exception.ExceptionResponse;
import com.example.demo.exception.BadRequestException;

@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class ResponseExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status,
            WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse(ex.getBindingResult().toString(), request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(
            Exception ex,
            WebRequest request){
        ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse(ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(response);
    }
}
```

Here is my model class:

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.constraints.Past;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Data
public class User {
    @Email(message = "Email is not valid", regexp = "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])")
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;

    @Size(min = 2, message = "First name should be at least 2 characters long")
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty("user_uuid")
    private String userUUID;

    @NotNull(message = "Password is required")
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String password;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "mm/dd/yyyy")
    @JsonProperty("date_of_birth")
    @Past
    private Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

What should I do for date format mismatch exception? Also, how to provide custom message for it?